# Allow filtering which types of on-site inbox notifications are sent to my email

Tags: feature-request, email

I would like to unsubscribe from minor edits to my questions and answers on the site - especially older questions that I have long forgotten and am not really interested (invested) in any more.

I find that for small changes, grammar and punctuation, and minor formatting, the email that advises me of the changes is not really productive.

Looking at the options on the email subscriptions, I do not see any option other than to modify the email schedule from every 3 hours to a weekly digest, to OFF.

[image]

I suppose then, if there is no way to do this currently, then this is a feature request. Perhaps someone particularly skilled can come up with a way of determining if a change is merely a matter of grammar and punctuation and/or minor formatting (bullets etc.).

That could be done by using certain metrics or an AI that can make a recognition of 'not minor change'.

Some alternatives might also be that the email could include the edit so that the user does not need to visit the site to see very minor edits. For example, "1 paragraph deleted" or "50 words deleted and moved
.

This might be a feature to some other people here, especially active users with lots of questions and answers. Perhaps the email subscriptions feature just needs to be more granular and provide some additional options that could be accommodated without any major changes.

For your consideration.

---

Example email that is received for an edit notification.
[image]

Comment: But what is the change is from `int` to `String`? Is that minor?

Comment: @Scratte Not sure. Let us say that I change the first 'is' in your comment to 'if'. Then that is definitely minor. I think algos exist that could detect that since it was in a sentence and not in quotes (markup) that it was a minor edit. Not sure about the specifics though -- it would have to be drafted and considered by the community.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I just don't think we can rely on AI to sort out what we think is minor compared to important. A small edit doesn't mean it's minor was my point. Even if it's not inline code or code in a code block, it could still be a small, but important change. Would a change to "I would like to subscribe to all edits to my questions and answers on the site" be minor? Sorry about the typo in my previous comment :)

Comment: @Scratte good points. Of course, the other options are still available. Users could subscribe to edits as a weekly digest and other notifications daily. So there are lots of options to either reduce or remove certain email notifications.

Answer (score 2):

First, it's worth noting that the current system is already designed to [avoid notifying you unless the edits are "substantive"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202415). The idea is that, if you get notification, it's a good idea to review the changes and make sure that they are in keeping with your intent. It also gives you a chance to make any *further* improvements that may become obvious to you after looking at the other user's suggestions.

These notifications come to your inbox on the site, along with other types of notifications, including replies (pings) in comments and chat. If you request that inbox notifications be emailed to you, then *all* of them will be copied and sent to your email. There's currently no way to configure which specific inbox notifications are sent to your email address. Adding this filtering would be a major new feature.

Frankly, as someone who gets dozens or more inbox notifications per day (almost *none* of which are announcing edits to my posts—I think I've gotten less than 20 of those in the past decade), I cannot imagine making use of a feature that would dump these inbox notifications to my email, which is already overflowing on its own. But if you're benefiting from it, then more power to you!

Until such time as this feature can be assessed and possibly implemented by the team, I'd recommend rolling your own filtering scheme on the client side (i.e., in your email client).